# Как сделать что бы Tor не участвовал в цепочке

Tags: linux, ip, tor

Нашел тут один вопрос на этом сайте но на него никто не дал ответа и он уже затерялся. Но меня волнует этот вопрос, я просто его скопирую.

Если на Linux установить и запустить Tor. То он начнает сразу раздавать трафик, я например хочу пользоваться Tor-ом но что бы мой комп **не участвовал в цепочке** на раздачу трафика. В Tor-браузере это реализовано, а как это сделать что бы пользоваться другими программами через Tor без раздачи трафика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Tor не будет подключаться к сети, он не сможет отправить/получить каких либо данных.

Если набрать команду `man tor`, вы можете там увидеть:

> By default, tor will act as a client only. To help the network by providing bandwidth as a relay, change the ORPort configuration option — see below. Please also consult the documentation on the Tor Project’s website.

Что означает:

По умолчанию tor будет работать только как клиент. Чтобы помочь сети, обеспечивая пропускную способность в качестве ретранслятора, измените параметр конфигурации ORPort. Обратитесь также к документации на сайте проекта Tor.

[Полный гайд по настройке Relay](https://gitlab.torproject.org/legacy/trac/-/wikis/TorRelayGuide)

[Мануал по настройке Tor](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) (тоже самое что и `man tor`)

По команде `git clone https://git.torproject.org/torspec.git` вы получите локальную копию документации со спецификацией всех процессов и сервисов Tor.

Внутри каталога вы найдете файлы:

- **tor-spec.txt**
  содержит спецификацию основного протокола Tor, это хорошее место для начала чтения.
- **cert-spec.txt** описывает формат сертификата, используемый
  в других частях протокола.
- **dir-spec.txt** определяет операции и форматы, используемые для
  поддержания представления сетевого каталога.
- **padding-spec.txt** описывает набор механизмов набивки,
  используемой для затруднения анализа трафика.
- **version-spec.txt** объясняет, как понимать номера версий Tor.
- **glossary.txt** - это глоссарий терминов, используемых
  в других спецификациях.
- **address-spec.txt** перечисляет набор специальных
  адресов, которые Tor обрабатывает иначе, чем обычная система DNS.
- **guard-spec.txt** объясняет алгоритм "сторожевого узла",
  который клиенты Tor используют для предотвращения атак через выборку.
- **path-spec.txt** объясняет, как клиенты выбирают свои пути
  через сеть Tor.
- **socks-extensions.txt** определяет специфичные для Tor
  расширения протокола SOCKS.
- **rend-spec-v2.txt** - это старая, устаревшая версия
  протокола луковых служб.
- **rend-spec-v3.txt** - текущая версия протокола лукового сервиса.
- **bridgedb-spec.txt** объясняет, каким образом bridgedb-сервер выдает мосты цензурированным клиентам.
- **gettor-spec.txt** описывает инструмент `gettor`,
  который используется для загрузки Tor в зонах цензуры.
- **pt-spec.txt** описывает протокол, который клиенты Tor
  и ретрансляторы используют для связи с подключаемыми транспортами, используемыми для обфускации трафика.
- **bandwidth-file-spec.txt** определяет формат файла, используемый инструментами измерения пропускной способности для сообщения о своих наблюдениях в службы управления каталогами.
- **srv-spec.txt** определяет протокол, который используют службы каталогов для безопасного вычисления общих случайных значений для сети.
- **control-spec.txt** объясняет протокол, используемый контроллерами для связи с запущенным процессом Tor.
- **dir-list-spec.txt** объясняет формат, используемый инструментами, такими как скрипты каталога отката, для вывода списка каталогов Tor для включения в исходный код Tor.
- В каталоге **attic** хранятся устаревшие или исторические документы.